Other than approximating the total energy of the system, what other information does the Hartree-Fock method provide?
In the Hartree-Fock method, one computes the energy of an interacting quantum-many body system, described by $H$, via taking a non-interacting trial ground state, $|\psi_{\mathrm{HF}}\rangle$, and minimizing the total Hartree-Fock energy,
$E_{\mathrm{HF}} = \langle\psi_{\mathrm{HF}}|H|\psi_{\mathrm{HF}}\rangle$ with respect to the atomic orbitals. Doing so then yields a set of self-consistent Hartree-Fock equations which allows you to determine both the Hartree-Fock energy and precise form of the atomic orbitals.
However, I am confused how one uses this technique to do anything other than compute the total Hartree-Fock energy. How does one use this method to predict phase transitions and different ordering phases based off the interaction strength?
Is the idea that, once you've solved the Hartree-Fock equations and constructed the optimal atomic orbitals and Hartree-Fock potential, you've essentially reduced the interacting electron problem back to an independent electron problem, and, from there, you can apply the usual machinery of solid-state physics to compute whatever quantities you’re interested in?

Hi meer23, welcome to PSE. Consider for the next time to use \langle and \rangle to get $\langle$ and $\rangle$, respectively. I've done that for you now.

In addition to energy, Hartree-Fock gives you the optimal wave function of the many-electron system (within the limits of the theory) as well. Any physical observable can be obtained from the wave function using the associated operators.
